# Upload large file 8GB with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello I'm asking if I can upload an 8GB file through phpmyadmin, if not, what is the maximum can uploaded by phpmyadmin?

This is part of the code from my php.ini file

```
post_max_size=500M
upload_max_filesize=500M
memory_limit=900M
```

Are there any other options or config?

Thank you

Comment: *can upload file with 8GB trough phpmyadmin* ... *i put this config on php.ini & still the page down after waitting some minutes* ... *post_max_size=500M / upload_max_filesize=500M* Did you ... did you expect limiting the maximum size to 0.5GB to work??

Comment: @Smart Josef, what solution did you try to apply?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would consider using a different method for uploading such a large file. Namely SFTP or FTP.

If you absolutely must use PHPMyAdmin, you will need to edit your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to be at least 8G, you will probably also need to edit `max_input_time`. Note that, due to the large upload size, even with these options set correctly, you are still likely to run into issues. See here for an example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Another option would be splitting the file into smaller chunks and uploading them separately, then merging the chunks back together once it has uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the max_execution_time in php.ini?
or set execution timeout in xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

* maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)

Comment: sure i'm using apache srv its $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for importing large MySQL files is import via command line using SSH access to your server. Because you will not be limited by the settings of the web server, PHP configuration settings or possible import script errors. The command will be as follows:

`mysql -p -u user_name database_name < file.sql`

Replace `user_name`, `database_name`, and `file.sql` with the actual name.

[This article](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/162) will be helpful.